# What's the name of the tiny grooves of a zipper?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in: "The speedy sound of a zipper going up the _____s."

Comment: Not a name for the grooves, but *teeth*. I googled "parts of a zipper".

Comment: "The speedy sound of a zipper *being zipped*"...

Comment: This really shows no effort of research.  Try googling "parts of a zipper".

Answer (score 1):

They are usually referred to as teeth, (but also chain or coil, see picture).

[Tooth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tooth):

> - [ C usually plural ] any of the row of points that stick out from the edge of a tool or piece of equipment, ***such as a comb, saw, or zip***.

Cambridge dictionary

[image]